# .net core LaunchSettings json set to production mode in project name but enters in the development mode

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, production-environment

I encounter a problem with LaunchSettings.json in .net core. I set my APP to Production mode in the profiles, but it enters the development mode. If i change the first IIS Express to production only then it enters in production mode. Why is this happening?

Here you can find a snippet of my json file.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:34527",
      "sslPort": 44378
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "DatingApp.API": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When you are debugging through visual studio these profiles are the options to debug the application if your option says IIS Express then this is the one that will be picked up. You need to pay attention to which launch profile is active and which server is being used to launch the application.

Comment: @NickPolyderopoulos I totally agree. I  tried to put the IIS Express as prod and the dating.API as development. And it still goes into the development environment in the startup class

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose the correct profile in the drop down menu when running the app.

[image]

If you want to run the app using the `DatingApp.API` profile, you need to manually change it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It totally makes sense. But even if i change it it behaves the same. It goes to PRODUCTION mode only if i set both of them to production. Whereas for instance, if i use the IIS Server -> Production it should go to production mode, but in my case it doesn`t. It does only if both of the profiles are set to prod mode

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project and changing the environments? That way you can see if it's a problem with your solution or with your computer.

Comment: Nope - I haven`t. Will give it a try perhaps